# How to force WebService reference to implement common interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm creating a study project using .net web services and I came across with this problem:
In order to provide for an opportunity to change the web server or even it's nature (it's the part of the task) I created an interface in a separate .dll that every possible (web)services must implement. Say,

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    // Group of methods which are used for login/logout
    bool isUserRegistered(string username);
    bool authorize(string username, string password);
    //...
}
```

And I make the web service implement this interface:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Server : System.Web.Services.WebService, IDataAccess
{
    //...
}
```

Then, in the client, I create a reference (namespace WebReference) to this service specifying to reuse type in all assemblies and try to do the following:

```
private IDataAccess webService = (IDataAccess)(new WebReference.Server());
```

but this assignment throws exception in runtime stating the convertion can't be done, and, indeed, in the Reference.cs (which is a part of what is created by adding reference to Web Service there is a redeclaration of Server class which doesn't declare IDataAccessImplementation:

```
public partial class Server : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol {
    //...
}
```

So, my question is how to make this reference implement that common interface IDataAccess without manually editting the file Reference.cs?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you really don't need to implement the interface on the server side - that will do nothing for the generated code.

Next, note that the declaration is of a *partial* class. You can use that to your advantage.

All you need to do is create *another* C# file, which has:

```
public partial class Server : SoapHttpClientProtocol, IDataAccess {}
```

That's *all* you need (in the right namespace and with the right `using` directives). No code - that's all provided in the generated class. The C# compiler will blend the two declarations, and then you can just use:

```
private IDataAccess webService = new WebReference.Server();
```

... or better yet, inject it via a constructor so that you can write tests which don't need to use the real implementation at all!

Comment: "you really don't need to implement the interface on the server side - that will do nothing for the generated code" - but then how can I insure that all web services impement the desired set of methods?

Comment: @Dmitry: Well if they don't, then the generated code on the *client* side won't properly implement the interface... so you can tell that way. It doesn't *hurt* to make the server side implement the interface too - I'm just saying it doesn't influence the generated code.